# How to greet a mathematician on his birthday with an excitement

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Someone told me this, but I dont get it. $$\Gamma (Happy Birthday + 1)$$ Why is this the way to greet a mathematician on his birthday with an excitement?

Comment: the gamma function extends $n!$, $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The joke is that

$$\Gamma(n + 1) = n!$$

is the factorial function. So

$$\Gamma(\text{Happy Birthday} + 1) = \text{Happy Birthday}!$$

Comment: since when is Happy Birthday a natural number?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Well, one does generally celebrate on natural-number # of years...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I suppose that by the time one learns of the gamma function, one has stopped celebrating half birthdays ;)